# Insert FileName into MS Word footer

Tags: microsoft-word

The company I work for requires that every document we provide has a footer. Currently we add the base footer:

> ABC Inc/{FileName}/{CreatedDate}/

to the Normal.dotm for everyone and they have to manually change their document's footer with the correct name and date:

> ABC Inc/Superuser Question/Sep 8 2009/

How can I change the **Normal.dotm** to automatically insert the file name and current date in the footer when the user saves their document?

Answer (score 3):

In Word 2007, edit the footer (Insert - Footer - Edit Footer).

- Type the "ABC Inc/"
- In the Ribbon, go to Insert, Quick Parts, Fields
- For the filename, use the field "FileName"
- Type the "/" separator
- For the date, use the field "SaveDate" (you can select the format)
- Type the ending "/"

Comment: This is not working with Templates

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: I added the fields to a template and saved as normal2.dotm. Replace normal.dotm with normal2.dotm. Create new document. Save new document as test_doc. Footer shows ABC Inc/normal2.dotm/XXX 0000/

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on Insert
2. Select Footer
3. Click on Edit Footer
4. Click on Insert again
5. Select Quick Parts
6. Select Fields and choose field you'd like (e.g. filename, page number, date, etc.)
7. Hit tab and enter more if necessary.

http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2010/08/04/add-the-filename-to-your-header-or-footer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

After you save the document the fields in the footer won't be updated to reflect the new name and date.
Do a print preview to force them to be updated and you should see this working. (likewise a print would do the same thing but waste paper...)